# how can you tell if liquids have different densities

Tags: homework-and-exercises

help me
i need an answer asap for finals

Answer (score 2):

By measuring & comparing the weights of each liquid as follows:

1. Ensure each liquid & a measuring container are at the same temperature.
2. Pour a specific volume of one liquid into the measuring container.
3. Measure & record the weight of the container & the liquid.
4. Empty, clean, & dry the measuring container.
5. Repeat steps 2-4 above until you have measured the individual weight of each of your liquids.  Ensure you pour the same volume into the measuring container for each liquid.
6. Compare the weights of all the liquids.  The heavier liquids are more dense than the lighter liquids because higher density substances have greater weight per unit volume.

hth

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to try determine the rate that the substance would sink or float. As in 1/2 cup of colored water, and half cup of colored oil, 1/2 cup colored corn syrup. This page gives you a good example http://www.stevespanglerscience.com/lab/experiments/seven-layer-density-column/. Try a densities column experiment. [preferably different colors ie. red wine vinegar, green olive oil, blue colored water] Take a tube, glass or vase. Pour the same amount of each liquid into the same vessel and note which is on top, middle, bottom. Or, place each liquid in a separate vessel. Note the rate of sink with objects dropped in. A grape, a dime, a cork, a grain of rice, etc. Try to determine whether heated or chilled these liquids behave differently. At extremes, we know that as water freezes, its density changes. Try different amounts of salt or sugar with lighter objects and determine whether this has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Archimedean method by marking a 'boat' of some sort with tick marks up the side and floating it in various liquids. The boat will float higher in denser liquids and lower in less dense liquids. If you know the density and geometry of the boat, you can even calculate the exact density of the liquid by how far it sinks, since the volume of liquid displaced will weigh equally to the submerged portion of the boat.